# Any way to find lists with same elements in python?

Tags: python

I've made a parser that adds to separate file a variable as a list (Variable is message id and the list contains date, time, symbol, side) that looks like this:

[image: output sample (3 messages)]

The goal here is to identify lists that have equal elements within them and if so execute action via flask.
The main issue is that the program is supposed to be constantly running with new lists being added so I cannot just compare certain lists to each other.
Instead what needs to be done is to compare ones that are being added to *all* previously added lists and identify equal ones. A reasonable solution seems to me is to read this file with lists as long as it is always open and work from there. Also message id can be added to the list instead of making it a variable. But I will have to call the list that makes a match by that id later.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events

@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def normal_handler(event):

    ...extracting date, time, etc...

    signal = [str(date) + ', ' + str(time) + ', ' + str(ticker) + ', ' + str(side)]

    f.write('id' + str(event.id) + ' = ' + '[')
    f.writelines(signal)
    f.write(']' + "\n")
    f.flush()

client.start()

f = open('messages.py', 'a', encoding="utf-8")

client.run_until_disconnected()

f.close()
```

Comment: Why are you making `signal` a list when it will neve have more than 1 element? Just make it a string and use `f.write(signal)`

Comment: I also recommend you learn about string formatting and f-strings. It will make your code much easier to read and write than all that concatenation and calling `str()`.

Comment: I'd highly recommend you use a database for this rather than a plaintext file. (And without a `.py` extension). Start here - https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: The answer to the question in your title is `if somelist in list_of_lists:` will search `list_of_lists` for a nested list that has the same elements as `somelist`.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)...[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ... 
[You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)